# Controller functions not found after IIS publish

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api2, publish

I have an ASP.NET 4.5.2 solution with WEB API 2 controllers, Owin Oauth 2 authorization and a front end client based on Angular 2.

The solution runs perfectly in the debugger, but when it is published to a website on a server running IIS 7, Calls to the controller methods are returned with code 404.

Logs produced by IIS:
http://www.filedropper.com/uex161219

HTTPERR file from %SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR: http://www.filedropper.com/httperr1

Any help on how to debug this or solve the problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by changing .NET Framework version of the Application Pool from 2.0 to 4.0.